# How to embed a child word document in a parent word document and keep them sync

Tags: ms-word

How to embed a child word document in a parent word document and keep them sync?

For example, suppose I have a parent word document **A** and 2 children documents **B** and **C**. I want to embed **B** and **C** into **X**.

Then if I update **B** document I also want to see the changes in **X**.

Is this a feature that word has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Inset|Object>Text from File. Using the 'Insert as Link' option, select the document you want to insert. From now on, any edits to the source document will be replicated in the destination document (check Word's 'Update automatic links on open' option). Similarly, you can update the source document from the destination document by editing the linked range and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.